# Why can't VMware virtual machine and XAMPP be used simultaneously on windows?

Tags: xampp, virtual-machine

Why can't VMware virtual machine and XAMPP be used simultaneously on windows?
I am totally a noob here.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You could have a port conflict.

Comment: how do i resolve it?

Comment: Find out what is using port 80 and turn it off. With Windows, I think it's netstat -a